# How do you get the style of color seen in these "urban decay" pictures?

Tags: post-processing, technique, reverse-engineering

I have been trying to get this "look" and I am not even sure what to call it.

Here is an example:

[image]

And another:
[image]

Are they just doing selective color filtering, or is there something else that I am not grasping such as removing vibrance or playing with saturation? Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm. Those images have a very different look to me, with, actually, very little in common other than the modern-ruins setting.

Comment: The parts I am seeing it the blues in the top, and the green in the bottom. It looks like both images have a high level of de-saturation but then there are some nice coloring as well.

Comment: Agred. very different images. The top is likely HDR. It could also be processed with the bleach bypass filter (the NIK Color Efex Pro Bleach Bypass filter yields a very similar result) It certainly has the structure cracked up quite a bit. As for the second image; i don;t think anything much other then saturation has been done to highlight the green.

Comment: Perhaps these images should be replaced with links to source? I doubt if author's permission was obtained to republish them, especially under the [CC license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) that applies to content of this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The top image is almost certainly HDR. Do a Google image search on HDR and you'll surely find others very much like it.

The bottom one is *possibly* HDR, although most people have trouble leaving as much solid shadow as is shown in that image. It kind of looks like what was there and from what I see there was light bouncing in through all kinds of doors and windows and reflecting off plenty of surfaces that could influence its color. I've been in settings like this and they photograph much like this with zero post-processing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes these images are taken using a technique called HDR, this stands for High Dynamic Range.

you are effectively taking three frames, one is under exposed, one correctly exposed and one is over exposed. They are then blended together into one image with a high dynamic range.

You will see in the images that the lights are bright and the darks are dark and that the in between shades are very detailed. This is the effect you get.